# Resize table header with contents

Tags: html, css

I have a table with contents inside of it. I would like to be able to resize the column to 0 pixels so it appears 'gone'. The problem is that since there are contents inside the header and cells, it will only resize down to the size of the content.

I simply want it to work like this: **if I set header width to 10px, it should become 10px wide, regardless of what's inside the header or the columns.**

I did a workaround by wrapping cell contents into a container, which is positioned absolute:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
      <th style="width:0px">
          <div class="cell-wrapper">Some super long content</div>
      </th>

      <th>
          <div class="cell-wrapper">More content, could be an image</div>
      </th>
   </tr>
 </table>

 .cell-wrapper
 {
     position: absolute;
 }
```

But there are multiple issues with this approach. Is there a way I can do this without the absolute positioning/container workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this..

```css
.cell-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
 <table>
   <tr>
      <th style="display: table-column;">
          <div class="cell-wrapper">Some super long content</div>
      </th>

      <th>
          <div class="cell-wrapper">Another cell with long text</div>
      </th>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: The column still collapses to the same width as the header text. If I set the header width to 10px, I want it to be 10px, regardless what's inside the columns